# If statement to check array values

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I want to display an answer based on what value in an array the user input matches. So I want the if statement to see if what was entered matches any values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` statement:

```
array = [1, 4, 9, 16]
element = int(input())
if element in array:
    print("Okay")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if value in array:
  dosomething
```